# How to make a dynamic JSON.parse() function that parse all the stated items in local storage

Tags: javascript

Is there any solution for this issue? I have 8 items in local storage that I want to parse dynamically. I cannot parse them using a for loop. The only solution I found is to write them one by one, and it works. However, I want a function that can dynamically parse all the targeted elements in local storage.

```js
arrList[2] = JSON.parse(localStorage.arrayItems2);

for (j = 2; j <= arrList[2].length; j++) {
arrList[`${j++}`] = JSON.parse(`localStorage.arrayItems${j++}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb 1 liner:

```
Array.from(Array(localStorage.length)).map((n, i) => localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))).map((item) => {try {return JSON.parse(item);} catch {return item;}});
```

You can use `localStorage.length` to get the number of keys. Then you can loop through each index and use `localStorage.key` to get the name of each key. Then use `localStorage.getItem` to get each item based on its key. Then try to parse the value with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This is a great snippet, and from researching to learn more about it, I found out `Array.from` also has a second argument that accepts a callback function to map through the array it created. I can't confirm benefits outside of aesthetics/code-golf, but it would end up like this: `Array.from(Array(localStorage.length), (n, i) => localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))).map((item) => {try {return JSON.parse(item);} catch {return item;}});`

Comment: Oh cool. I almost never use Array.from so I always have to look it up and I didn’t notice the second argument. 

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the property by name.

```js
for (j = 2; j <= listarrays[2].length; j++) {
    listarrays[j++] = JSON.parse(localStorage.[`arrayItems${j++}`]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many of issue in this code, you are parse string with name localStorage.arrayItem nested of fetch local storage data, and you are missing keys list and you dont pssing these keys to fetch, also you are increment j twice and so on...

to resolve this issue I make this example for you (its general example in top layer) and you can convert it to work with your example here if you needed it in inner level

```js
  const listOfKeys = ["t1", "t2", "t3","userData", "InfoData", "moreData"]
  let listarrays = {};

  localStorage.setItem("t1", JSON.stringify(listOfKeys));
  localStorage.setItem("t2", JSON.stringify([1, 2]));
  localStorage.setItem("t3", JSON.stringify([3, 4]));
  localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify([5, 6]));
  localStorage.setItem("InfoData", JSON.stringify([7, 8]));
  localStorage.setItem("moreData", JSON.stringify([9, 10]));
  localStorage.setItem("listOfKeys", JSON.stringify(listOfKeys));

//Functional
  let keysList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listOfKeys"));
  console.log(keysList);
//Problem how to make this one loop through all arrayItems(2 - 10) and parse them dynamicaly from local storage
  for (let j = 2; j < keysList.length; j++) {
    let temp = localStorage.getItem(keysList[j])
    listarrays[j] = JSON.parse(temp);
  }

  console.log(listarrays)
```